# Approaching an inverse trigonometry problem using complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> If $\arctan x + \arctan y + \arctan z = \pi$, prove that $x+y+z= xyz$.

Please let me know if this is solvable through complex numbers?

I tried to define three complex numbers in the argand plane and then use the property $\arg(x)+ \arg(y)+\arg(z)= \arg(xyz)$ but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that since $\arctan x + \arctan y + \arctan z = \pi$ and range of $\arctan$ is $(-\pi/2, \pi / 2) $ so we must have that $\arctan x, \arctan y, \arctan z \gt 0$ or that $x,y,z$.

Consider complex numbers $z_1(1,x), z_2(1,y), z_3(1,z)$ on Argand plane. Now these equivalent complex numbers must lie in quadrant I. Then $\arg(z_1) = \arctan(x)$ etc. meaning 
$$\arg(z_1 ) + \arg(z_2) + \arg(z_3) = \arctan(x)+\arctan(y)+\arctan(z) = \pi \tag{1}$$

Now consider the following expression $\zeta$:
 $$\zeta=\arg(z_1 ) + \arg(z_2) + \arg(z_3) = \arg(z_1 z_2 z_3) \\
= \arg((1+xi)(1+yi)(1+zi))\\=\arg(1-(xy+yz+zx)+i(x+y+z-xyz))$$

And this is equal to $\pi$ implying $\Im(\zeta) =0$ or that $x+y+z -xyz =0 \,\blacksquare$

Comment: Why did you chose $(1,x);(1,y); (1,z)$?

Comment: So that arctan and arg could be related.

Comment: I mean why not $(2,x); (3,y); (1,z)$?

Comment: Because then arg and arctan could not be related. What's bothering you so much? Do you not like the number one?

Comment: Nope, I am fine with 1. But its choice here is bothering me...I mean we won't get the same result if used other numbers.

Comment: Really? What I wrote is without loss of generality true for all x,y,z greater than zero which is required as per problem statement. "... We won't get same results if we used ..." what results are you getting with other numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72812/discussion-between-abcd-and-king-tut).